# Gnome can do multi-monitors, KDE can't

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome, kde, display-settings

I have both Gnome and KDE installed on my system. In Gnome I am able to split my desktop across my two monitors. When I go into KDE the monitors are cloned, and when I try to go into the multi-monitor settings, it says that its not able to do it.

Comment: Some more information will be helpful; what linux distro are you using? Are you using Compiz? What kind of video card do you have?

Comment: Yeah, the extra information will be essential. I know that KDE is able to split its desktop over multiple monitors because that's the setup I have on the computer I'm currently using, but there's probably some configuration you'd have to change in order to do it, and that depends on your underlying hardware and software.

Comment: I'm using compiz in Gnome, not sure if it's on in KDE. I'm using an onboard video card which has two connections. It's an ATI Radeon HD 4200.

Comment: using the open-source drivers, or fglrx? I'm not sure how well fglrx plays with xrandr.

Comment: I'm using the open-source drivers. If I use fglrx then it will work but if I use fglrx then that causes other weird problems in Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

i successfully used /usr/bin/krandrtray from the package "kdebase-workspace"
to manually set the position of the second monitor.  [image: krandrtray Multiple Monitors tab].
i wonder if the program you used from within KDE was actually the one for gnome?  i seem to recall that was my problem at first.

My box is CentOS6.4 gnome and KDE.

```
$ kded4 --version
Qt: 4.6.2
KDE: 4.3.4 (KDE 4.3.4)
KDE Daemon: $Id: kded.cpp 1031638 2009-10-05 16:59:11Z lunakl $
```